# SAS date parameter

Tags: sas

I have a table like TABLE_NAME_&DATE. The &DATE. parameter is dynamic and each month should be shown like MMYYYY (previous month and couurent year). e.g TABLE_NAME_JAN2022

This parameter will be created in User Written Code inside a job.

My query is what code should I put to make this table dynamic and recived monthly table with data paramter for previous month

Thank you

Comment: Are you looking for a way to define the value of DATE?  How are you running SAS?  Are you using SAS directly as batch job or using Display Manager user interface? Or are you using some front end application like Enterprise Guide or SAS/Studio?  What style to you want to use for DATE?  With letter for the month like JAN2022 or with digits for the month like you first indicated by using MMYYYY which would by 012022 for January of 2022.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the DATE() , also known as TODAY(), function to get the current date.  You can use the INTNX() function to find the previous month.  You can use the MONYY7. format to generate a string in MONYYYY style. You can use CALL SYMPUTX() function to store the string into a macro variable.

```
data _null_;
   call symputx('date',put(intnx('month',date(),-1),monyy7.));
run;
```

If you want to do it with only macro code you will need to wrap the DATE() and INTNX() function calls inside of %SYSFUNC() macro function calls.

```
%let date=%sysfunc(intnx(month,%sysfunc(date()),-1),monyy7.);
```